# Proof that a linear transformation is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations, diagonalization

> Prove that for $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T=T^2$, $T$ is diagonalizable.

**My Work -**

Let $A_n$ represent the representative matrix of $T$, therefore -

$ \forall \,v\in V$ we can say that $Av = A^2v \iff A^2v-Av = 0 \iff A(Av-Iv)=0$

So either our Matrix A is the zero matrix with is diagonal, or $\forall v\in V$ we can say that $Av - Iv = 0 \iff Av = Iv$.

Now, what we can conclude (?) is that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ for every $v\in V$, so can i say that the geometric and algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is  $n$ ?

Comment: Do we have $V = \Bbb C^n$?

Comment: The multiplicity of $1$ will be $\textrm{tr}(A)=\textrm{rk}(A)$.

Comment: The minimal polynomial $T(T-I)$ has no repeated factors.